# Django Models filter only last records

Tags: django, filter

I m developing a CRM using Django , my goal is to get a list of only last records of a model, my  models like below

```
class Rapport(models.Model):
    added=models.DateField(default=timezone.now,blank=True,db_index=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    image2=models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=upload_location2)
    can_update=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    note=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,db_index=True)
    observation=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)


class Visite(models.Model):
    rapport=models.ForeignKey(Rapport,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    observation=models.TextField()
    medecin=models.ForeignKey(Medecin,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    produits=models.ManyToManyField(Produit,through='produits.ProduitVisite')
    priority=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,db_index=True)


class Medecin(models.Model):
    nom=models.CharField(max_length=255,db_index=True)
    telephone=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email=models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
    commune=models.ForeignKey(Commune,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adresse=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    flag=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updatable=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    contact=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    users=models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I want to get only the last Visite object  of each Medecin a dirty way of doing it would be like so :

```
last_visites=[Visite.objects.filter(medecin=medecin)[-1] for medecin in Medcin.objects.all()]
```

Answer (score 0):

May this method will give you what you want :

```
medecin_last_visit_ids = Medecin.objects.values('id','visite__id').order_by('-visite__id').distinct('id')
```

`

Comment: i got this error `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend` i suppose that mysql does not support distinct by field